# Gradients vanishing despite using Kaiming initialization

Tags: pytorch, gradient

I was implementing a conv block in pytorch with activation function(prelu). I used Kaiming initilization to initialize all my weights and set all the bias to zero. However as I tested these blocks (by stacking 100 such conv and activation blocks on top of each other), I noticed that the output I am getting values of the order of  10^(-10). Is this normal, considering I am stacking upto 100 layers. Adding a small bias to each layer fixes the problem. But in Kaiming initialization the biases are supposed to be zero.

Here is the conv block code

```
from collections import Iterable

def convBlock(
    input_channels, output_channels, kernel_size=3, padding=None, activation="prelu"
):
    """
    Initializes a conv block using Kaiming Initialization
    """
    padding_par = 0
    if padding == "same":
        padding_par = same_padding(kernel_size)
    conv = nn.Conv2d(input_channels, output_channels, kernel_size, padding=padding_par)
    relu_negative_slope = 0.25
    act = None
    if activation == "prelu" or activation == "leaky_relu":
        nn.init.kaiming_normal_(conv.weight, a=relu_negative_slope, mode="fan_in")
        if activation == "prelu":
            act = nn.PReLU(init=relu_negative_slope)
        else:
            act = nn.LeakyReLU(negative_slope=relu_negative_slope)
    if activation == "relu":
        nn.init.kaiming_normal_(conv.weight, nonlinearity="relu")
        act = nn.ReLU()
    nn.init.constant_(conv.bias.data, 0)
    block = nn.Sequential(conv, act)
    return block


def flatten(lis):
    for item in lis:
        if isinstance(item, Iterable) and not isinstance(item, str):
            for x in flatten(item):
                yield x
        else:
            yield item


def Sequential(args):
    flattened_args = list(flatten(args))
    return nn.Sequential(*flattened_args)
```

This is the test Code

```
ls=[]
for i in range(100):
    ls.append(convBlock(3,3,3,"same"))
model=Sequential(ls)

test=np.ones((1,3,5,5))
model(torch.Tensor(test))
```

And the output I am getting is

```
tensor([[[[-1.7771e-10, -3.5088e-10,  5.9369e-09,  4.2668e-09,  9.8803e-10],
          [ 1.8657e-09, -4.0271e-10,  3.1189e-09,  1.5117e-09,  6.6546e-09],
          [ 2.4237e-09, -6.2249e-10, -5.7327e-10,  4.2867e-09,  6.0034e-09],
          [-1.8757e-10,  5.5446e-09,  1.7641e-09,  5.7018e-09,  6.4347e-09],
          [ 1.2352e-09, -3.4732e-10,  4.1553e-10, -1.2996e-09,  3.8971e-09]],

         [[ 2.6607e-09,  1.7756e-09, -1.0923e-09, -1.4272e-09, -1.1840e-09],
          [ 2.0668e-10, -1.8130e-09, -2.3864e-09, -1.7061e-09, -1.7147e-10],
          [-6.7161e-10, -1.3440e-09, -6.3196e-10, -8.7677e-10, -1.4851e-09],
          [ 3.1475e-09, -1.6574e-09, -3.4180e-09, -3.5224e-09, -2.6642e-09],
          [-1.9703e-09, -3.2277e-09, -2.4733e-09, -2.3707e-09, -8.7598e-10]],

         [[ 3.5573e-09,  7.8113e-09,  6.8232e-09,  1.2285e-09, -9.3973e-10],
          [ 6.6368e-09,  8.2877e-09,  9.2108e-10,  9.7531e-10,  7.0011e-10],
          [ 6.6954e-09,  9.1019e-09,  1.5128e-08,  3.3151e-09,  2.1899e-10],
          [ 1.2152e-08,  7.7002e-09,  1.6406e-08,  1.4948e-08, -6.0882e-10],
          [ 6.9930e-09,  7.3222e-09, -7.4308e-10,  5.2505e-09,  3.4365e-09]]]],
       grad_fn=<PreluBackward>)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazing question (and welcome to StackOverflow)! [Research paper for quick reference](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.01852.pdf).

### TLDR

- Try wider networks (`64` channels)
- Add Batch Normalization after activation (or even before, shouldn't make much difference)
- Add residual connections (shouldn't improve much over batch norm, last resort)

Please check this out in this order and give a comment what (and if) any of that worked in your case (as I'm also curious).

### Things you do differently

- Your neural network is very deep, yet **very narrow** (`81` parameters per layer only!)

Due to above, one cannot reliably create those weights from normal distribution as the sample is just too small.

**Try wider networks, `64` channels or more**

- **You are trying much deeper network than they did**

**Section: Comparison Experiments**

> We conducted comparisons on a deep but efficient model with  14  weight
> layers (actually `22` was also tested in comparison with `Xavier`)

That was due to date of release of this paper (`2015`) and hardware limitations "back in the days" (let's say)

### Is this normal?

Approach itself is quite strange with layers of this depth, at least currently;

- each conv block is usually followed by activation like `ReLU` **and Batch Normalization** (which normalizes signal and helps with exploding/vanishing signals)
- usually networks of this depth (even of depth half of what you've got) use also residual connections (though this is not directly linked to vanishing/small signal, more connected to degradation problem of even deep networks, like `1000` layers)

Comment: Hey thanks for helping me out. I was just testing it to see how I was performing using the He initialization. The test model does not represent any final work. I get your point. Actually I am going to use this to work on super resolution. I have seen a few papers and they say batch normalization is not good for super resolution task. But yes there are skip connections and a larger number of filters, so things should be fine. Again thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes i used wider networks it was 10 or 11 layers deep with skip connections. It was working fine.